# Eager Load Entity Framework Navigation Property error

Tags: entity-framework, navigation, poco, eager-loading

I'm trying to eager load some child entities like so:

```
_context.Sites.Where(x => x.ID == siteID).Include(s => s.SiteLoggers).FirstOrDefault();
```

However, the error I am getting is:

```
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'MyProject.Dal.EF.Site' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'SiteLoggers'.
```

What is saying is correct, as MyProject.Dal.EF.Site does not exist, the object exists in MyProject.Domain.Entities.Site

What am I missing??? Thanks!

POCOs:

```
namespace MyProject.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Site
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int LocationID { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<SiteLogger> SiteLoggers { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyProject.Domain.Entities
{
    public class SiteLogger
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int UID { get; set; }
        public int SiteID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int LocationID { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable`, because EF requires that your navigation properties are defined as `ICollection<T>.`

```
 public virtual ICollection <SiteLogger> SiteLoggers { get; set; }
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! That would explain some other odd behaviour too! Should have come here first before spending half a day trawling the net.